# Why mod $p$ gates cannot be computed by $ACC^0[q]$ circuits, $p$ and $q$ prime

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

I am going through Computational Complexity by Arora and Barak, and there I came across the proof of why mod $p$ gates cannot be computed by $ACC^0[q]$ circuits, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. The book proves it for $p=2$ and $q=3$, and I am facing difficulties generalizing this result for arbitrary $p$ and $q$.

The proof uses two lemmas. The first one states that any $ACC^0[3]$ circuit can be approximated via a low degree polynomial $\in F_3[x]$. The change in the first lemma to generalize it to arbitrary primes, $p$ and $q$, is straightforward.

But in the second lemma, where they changed $f\colon\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}$ to $f\colon\{-1,1\}^n\to\{-1,1\}$ and defined a function $\prod_{i=1}^n y_i$ which represents parity, I do not quite get how to generalize to arbitrary $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Try replacing $\{-1,1\}$ with the set of $p$th roots of unity.

Comment: How to change $\{0,1\}$ to $\{1,\zeta_p\}$ without changing the criteria $deg(f)<n^{1/2}$ ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The polynomial $\prod_{i=1}^n y_i$ has degree $n$.

Comment: I mean what transformation should I use?

Comment: How about $x \mapsto 1 + (\zeta_p-1)x$? It has degree 1, just like the special case $x \mapsto 1-2x$.

Comment: How $\prod_{i=1}^n y_i \in \{1,\zeta_p\}$. There should be an exponent right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113689/discussion-between-diptajit-roy-and-yuval-filmus).

Comment: The idea is that $\prod_i (1 + (\zeta_p-1) x_i) = \prod_i \zeta_p^{x_i} = \zeta_p^{\sum_i x_i} = \zeta_p^{\sum_i x_i \bmod p}$. You'll have to figure out the rest on your own.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Sir